# What is the word/phrase that describes a situation at which between 2 sides, it is hard to decide which side will win?

Tags: word-choice

What is the word/phrase that describes a situation at which between 2 sides, it is hard to decide which side will win? For example, in football, when 2 teams are competitive but cannot get out of a draw, and maintain at that situation.

Comment: "Stalemate", "too close to call" cover a couple of the meanings suggested by your question.

Comment: The contestants are 'neck and neck'. Interestingly, when I entered "neck and neck evenly matched too close to call" into an in-house search to check for duplicates, I got the single return: 'The etymology of "to prove dough" '.

Answer (score 2):

**Evenly matched**

> Two people or teams who are evenly matched are equally good, or have an equal chance of winning.
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/evenly)

Answer (score 0):

If two opponents, whether in sports or an election, are evenly matched or polling suggests  close result, then it's called a [*tossup*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tossup) or, still retaining the hyphen, *toss-up.*

If the outcome is predicted to be very close, one might call it a race to a [*photo finish*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/photo-finish?s=t). The term comes primarily from horseracing before extremely precise timekeeping devices, where a photograph was used to determine which horse's nose was first over the finish line.

> The American electorate has a fundamental tendency to divide closely, with ["photo finish"](https://books.google.de/books?id=mENqG8QIyPgC&q=%22photo+finish%22+election&dq=%22photo+finish%22+election&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR-9DP2e7ZAhUpI8AKHZ4GAyAQ6AEIVDAI) elections being almost the rule rather than the exception.